# Update SQL table with values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
      Feature
     ----------
    id   ExtractedId
    1       12
    2       5

    ExtractedFeature
   ------------------
     Id   Number
     1      12
     7      5
```

Expected Output

```
   Feature
 ------------- 
id    ExtractedId
1         1
2         7

   ExtractedFeature
-----------------------
 id        number
  1          12
  7           5
```

So ExtractedId from Feature table is the same as number from ExtractedFeature.

But I want ExtractedId in the feature table to be the id from the extractedfeature table.

How do I do this `UPDATE` query?

Comment: Can you also add expected result?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Daniel , What is the common field of these two tables. other wise it is difficult to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Update with inner Join for this

```
 UPDATE F
SET F.ExtractedId = E.Id
FROM Feature as F 
INNER JOIN ExtractedFeature as E 
    ON F.ExtractedId = E.Number
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
UPDATE Feature
SET F.ExtractedId = E.Id
FROM Feature F INNER JOIN ExtractedFeature E 
    ON F.ExtractedId = E.Number
```

Hope this helps.